# Prove $\arg(z + w) = \frac{\arg(z) + \arg(w)}{2}$ whenever $|z| = |w| = 1$

Tags: complex-numbers

I came across this problem the other day and I am still scratching my head how to solve part ii) algebraically (rather than graphically).

Let $z = \operatorname{cis} \theta$ and $w = \operatorname{cis} \phi$, given that $ |z| = |w| = 1$.

i) Evaluate $ z + w $ in mod-arg form.

ii) HENCE show that $ \arg (z + w) = 1/2 (\arg z + \arg w) $.

OK. I can do part i), by using sum to product identities. My answer is:

$$
 z + w = 2 \cos \left(\frac {\theta - \phi}{2}\right)\operatorname{cis} \left(\frac {\theta + \phi}{2}\right).
$$

However, I'm unsure how to proceed with part ii), solving this problem algebraically. (I can do it graphically).

Any direction is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The claim has some issues with the branch cut of $\arg$. For example, if $z=\operatorname{cis} \frac{3\pi}{4}$ and $w=\operatorname{cis} \frac{5\pi}{4}$, then $\arg(z+w) = \pi$ but $\arg z + \arg w = 0$.

Comment: Brilliant... so easy!  $r = 2 \cos \left(\frac{\theta - \phi}{2}\right)... $  why did I not see this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us do it step by step. To begin with, notice that
\begin{align*}
\cos(a + b) + \cos(a - b) & = \cos(a)\cos(b) -  \sin(a)\sin(b) + \cos(a)\cos(b) + \sin(a)\sin(b)\\\\
& = 2\cos(a)\cos(b)
\end{align*}

Similarly, we do also have that
\begin{align*}
\sin(a + b) + \sin(a - b) & = \sin(a)\cos(b) + \sin(b)\cos(a) + \sin(a)\cos(b) - \sin(a)\cos(b)\\\\
& = 2\sin(a)\cos(b)
\end{align*}
Consequently, the following identity holds:
\begin{align*}
\cos(\theta) + \cos(\varphi) = 2\cos\left(\frac{\theta + \varphi}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\theta - \varphi}{2}\right)
\end{align*}
Similarly, one has that
\begin{align*}
\sin(\theta) + \sin(\varphi) = 2\sin\left(\frac{\theta + \varphi}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\theta - \varphi}{2}\right)
\end{align*}

Hence it results that:
\begin{align*}
z + w = 2\cos\left(\frac{\theta - \varphi}{2}\right)\left[\cos\left(\frac{\theta + \varphi}{2}\right) + i\sin\left(\frac{\theta + \varphi}{2}\right)\right]
\end{align*}

just as you did. Based on such results, it yields that:
\begin{align*}
\arg(z + w) = \arctan\left(\tan\left(\frac{\theta + \varphi}{2}\right)\right) = \frac{\theta + \varphi}{2} = \frac{\arg(z) + \arg(w)}{2}
\end{align*}

and we are done.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Great where $r = 2 \cos \left(\frac{\theta - \phi}{2}\right)... $ .  So easy when can see it!  Thanks for your effort.

Comment: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/WernerFormulas.html and https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html

Answer (score 1):

Comment:

The following is your calculation: $$
 z + w = 2 \cos \left(\frac {\theta - \phi}{2}\right)cis \left(\frac {\theta + \phi}{2}\right).
$$

Then by the definition of Arg, you prove the expected identity. I mean you've solved your problem. Note that in this argument, it's assumed that $ \theta -\phi$ is not an odd multiple of $ \pi/2.$

One more comment:

You mentioned that you don't want any pictorial/geometric solution, but I find geometric/pictorial proof more insightful, at least in this case. For example, in this problem, you can imagine that the two complex numbers form a rhombus (I am assuming that the difference of arguments is not $\pi/2$ ie two vectors that represent the two given complex numbers are not orthogonal.) Then the diagonal (the one that passes through the origin) represents the sum of two complex numbers, and its argument is $\frac{1}{2} (\theta -\phi)$ + $\phi.$ WLOG, we're assuming $ \theta$ is bigger than $\phi.$

Comment: Yeah.. I did solve this problem diagrammatically. You are correct that the two complex numbers form a rhombus.  Thanks again for your input.  Greatly appreciated.

Comment: A square is a rhombus too.